# Unable to perform this action because the process is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When I try to run the .NET Core sample program on my MAC. on VScode.

On Terminal is ok.

```
bogon:projectApp JCNetwork-Mecil9$ dotnet run
Project projectApp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.

What is your name?
mecil9

Hello, mecil9, on 12/10/2016 at 17:11
```

but on VSCode ,throw out the error:

```
What is your name?

mecil9

Unable to perform this action because the process is running.
```

Comment: when i stop debug, throw next error: '.../projectApp.dll 'has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).

Answer (score 18):

The reason why that is happening is because, you are trying to use the debug console as a terminal to your application and at the time you entered an input, it was already running a process which is your application. So in simple terms, what it is trying to tell you is that, 'I can't do what you are asking me to do now because I'm already running a program'. What you need to do for your console app to run is that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to open the Debug section. At the top, you will find a gear sign which opens a file called 'launch.json'. Search for **"externalConsole"** and change it from **false** to **true**. This will open a console window for you to allow for input. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I turned the "externalConsole" parameter to "true", but now even debugging doesn't start. I see something like this **The preLaunchTask 'g++ build active file' terminated with exit code 1.** Do you have any idea for this situation?

Comment: I have externalConsole to true but no console window pops up for input

Comment: This solved my problem. I was trying to debug a CPP program & this same error was popping

Thanks

Comment: @Keyyubi I came across the same problem as you. The debugger just hung after I  turned the `externalConsole` parameter to `true`. How did you end up dealing with the problem?

Comment: @FavonianKong Unfortunately I don't even remember the problem now :( I've not been using .NET Core since 2 years. But it might related with C compiler or it's configs (g++ build)

Comment: @GeekLee a very in depth solution to your old problem can probably be found here in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353561/6837209

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for solution for MacOS. The only working option I found to run debugging in VS Code with **internal** terminal is to install extension called **CodeLLDB** [Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb).

Here is my launch.json configuration file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: This is the only way i got it to work using MacOS Sonoma. You may refer to following post on github which refers to the same issue
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9025#issuecomment-1777156301

Answer (score 3):

After setting "**externalConsole**" to '**true**' in '**launch.json**' VSCode launches the debug adapter, then the debug adapter launches lldb-mi, then lldb-mi launches Terminal. There is a prompt that should appear, but somehow the DebugAdapter is not forwarding this permissions request. To fix this issue add this to '**tasks.json**':

{
    "label": "Open Terminal",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"\ndo script "echo hello"\nend tell'",
    "problemMatcher": []
}

You can run this specific task using Command + Shift + p. Type Tasks and look for Tasks: Run Tasks then select Open Terminal.

The original issue and resolution can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5079#issuecomment-626090192).

Comment: For those who are on the latest version of Mac, which is everybody, this is what will solve the problem for you, combined with the suggestion provided by @alf-moh

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me:

Install the extension Code Runner in VS Code

1. Go to VS Code Settings
2. Search for 'Run in Terminal'
3. Mark the CheckBox 'Code-runner: Run in Terminal'