# How to run program in a pop-out console window using VS Code?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

Currently my C++ program runs embedded in the VS Code window, right at the bottom panel. How can I run it in an individual console window as it is in VS?

I tried to turn the "settings/Terminal/Explorer" option "Kind" from "integrated" to "External" but it was no good.

Comment: You mean just by running the project from within using VSC using F5?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, still you shouldn't be using VIsual Studio Code for C++ if you're on Windows. You should be using Visual Studio IDE. In Visual Studio, just launching the application will execute in a seperate terminal window.

Comment: @Nina Thanks, I have installed both VS and VSC on my PC. It bores me to create a project for each case. I practice with many little cases, you know,  because I am new to coding...

Comment: I had the same problem, here's the solution I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221544/how-to-make-code-runner-run-in-external-terminal-command-prompt Just add those code lines into your settings.json file :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) that runs your app in your OS's native terminal/console.

For example I have this very simple test file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main (void)
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

1st, install [Microsoft's C/C++ VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)  to add support for debugging C++ files.

2nd, create a build task. Open the command palette, find **Tasks: Configure Tasks** then select a suitable C++ compiler (ex. g++ in my case). If this is the first time you are doing this, VS Code is going to create a **.vscode/tasks.json** folder in your workspace with a default task. Configure it to build your app, like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build-test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/app/test.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/app/test"
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

3rd, create the launch task. Open the Debug panel. If you are doing this for the first time and you have no existing launch configurations, just click on the **create a launch.json file** link:

[image: VS Code - Debug Panel - no existing configurations]

If you already have existing configurations, open the dropdown and select **Add Config**.

[image: VS Code - Debug Panel - dropdown with existing configurations]

It should open up the existing launch.json file and show you a popup of which type of launch configuration to use. Select **C++** with **Launch**

[image: VS Code - launch.json - C/C++ option]

Update the configuration like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run-test",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build-test",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app/test",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "args": [],
            "environment": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

The important configs here are `"preLaunchTask": "..."` and `"externalConsole": true`. The `preLaunchTask` should be set to the build task set earlier. The `externalConsole`, if set to `false` it opens it in the Integrated Console. Since you *don't* want to run it in the Integrated Console, set it to `true`.

Now, whenever you want to run your app, just open the Debug panel, then run your launch task (same name as the `name` you set in the *launch.json*). Note that in the *launch.json* config, I set `stopAtEntry` to `true`, to give me a chance to see the external console window and then provide input to the prompt. You can remove it if you don't need it.

[image]

[image]

If all goes well, it's going to run it by launching an external console.

For more information, the complete guide to setting this up is in VS Code's [Configuring C/C++ debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) docs.

Comment: Thanks, I have found where the problem is.

Comment: No property called `externalConsole`, had to use `"console": externalTerminal`, however that gives an error related to debugging and doesn't pass the parameters to the program on start

Comment: @rboy There _is_ an `externalConsole`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole. As I mentioned in my answer, make sure to install [Microsoft's C/C++ extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), make sure you are editing the launch.json file, and make sure the launch config is of `"type": "cppdbg"`. Just checked it now with VS Code 1.63.2 and C/C++ extension v1.1.0 and [I have `externalConsole`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJDqX.png).

Comment: Okay I got it to work for a random external console program. Remove `MIMode`, set `"type": "cppvsdbg"` and instead of `externalConsole` use `"console": "externalTerminal"` and `"stopAtEntry": false`

Comment: @rboy You could post that as a separate answer since that's complete different from I posted on mine. So that others can have an alternative if my solution doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code for Windows

This is a modified version of the answer by [@gino-mempin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353561/2280961) which allows you to launch an external program from VSCode ***without*** having VSCode trying to attach to the launched program (thinking it's a debugger) which could lead to an error after launch. You can optionally configure the launch task to run build tasks prior to launching the external program.

Additional references https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

**You FIRST need to install [Microsoft's C/C++ VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) before using this launch configuration**.

Then configure your `launch.json` file like this (uncomment any optional parameters which you may need):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Start External Program",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "< the path to your exe to launch >",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            //"cwd": "optional working directory",
            //"args" : [ "optional arguments", "each argument is enclosed in quotes", "separated by commas" ],
            //"preLaunchTask": "optional name of pre launch build task",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually pretty easy. Open a new window of VS code and open terminal. And copy paste exact command of compiling and running the C++ program. So in this was you have 1 window for code browsing and another from program execution.