# How to see the console on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, console

Can somebody tell me how I can view console logs and things like that inside of vs code?  I am on Chromebook with Linux.  Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Toggle debug console: press `Ctrl+Shift+Y`

Toggle terminal: press `Ctrl+ù`

Answer (score 1):

Even though it has been 2 years since this question was asked, I want to put in what I found since this answer didn't help my problem. I figured it out from an answer Gino Mempin gave in [A question about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352944/how-to-run-program-in-a-pop-out-console-window-using-vs-code).
I am working with JavaScript and to get a Windows Console open in VS Code, go to your HTML file and click on the Run and Debug icon and click Run and Debug. Specify which browser you want if it asks, then open your Debug Console. It will work just like the Console in your Windows Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the terminal in VSC is by pushing Ctrl and ` together on the keyboard. You can also access the debug console, output, etc through that window.